Clarification on the definition of normal family
In Complex Function Theory, 2nd edition by Donald Sarason, the author defines normal families as follows:
A family of holomorphic functions in a domain is called a normal family if every sequence from the family has either a locally uniformly convergent subsequence or a subsequence that diverges locally uniformly to $\infty$.
In Functions of One Complex Variable, 2nd edition. by John B. Conway, the author defines normal families as follows:
Let $G \subset \mathbb{C}$ be open and $(\Omega, d)$ a complete metric space. Denote by $C(G, \Omega)$ the set of all continuous functions from $G$ to $\Omega$. A subset $\mathscr{F} \subset C(G, \Omega)$ is normal if each sequence in $\mathscr{F}$ has a subsequence which converges locally uniformly to some $f \in C(G, \Omega)$.
Sarason's definition is a special case of Conway's definition by letting $G \subset \mathbb{C}$ to be a domain and $\Omega = \mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$. The boldface part is equivalent to saying that the subsequence converges locally uniformly to the constant function from $G$ to $\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$ which identically takes the value $\infty$, and this constant function is in the space $C(G, \mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\})$. Thus, Sarason's definition can be restated as follows:
A family of holomorphic functions in a domain $G$ is called a normal family if every sequence from the family has a subsequence that converges locally uniformly to some continuous function from $G$ to $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$.
Is my understanding correct?
